# Dynamic flow types in React component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Please help me to resolve case described below. I have React component (called Test) that use properties that different only in one field (that field has no influence on what component do). But flow complains on that property when I use this component and I have no idea how to resolve it correctly. Help me please if you have experience in resolution cases like this. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const Obj1 = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
const Obj2 = {c: 'c', d: 'd'};

type TypesForA = $Values<typeof Obj1>;
type TypesForB = $Values<typeof Obj2>;

type A = Array<{|
  a: number,
  b: TypesForA,
|}>

type B = Array<{|
  a: number,
  b: TypesForB,
|}>

type Props = {prop: A | B};
type State = {prop: A | B};

export class Test extends Component<Props, State> {
   state = {prop: this.props.prop}
   render() {return null}

}

class Wrapper1 extends Component {     
   render() {
       return <Test prop={[{a: 1, b: Obj1}]}/> 
   }       
}


class Wrapper2 extends Component {     
   render() {
       return <Test prop={[{a: 1, b: Obj2}]}/> 
   }       
}
```

Flow errors: [image]

Comment: Two things I noticed, I don't think you want `$Values`, here, because `$Values<typeof Obj1>` is equivalent to `string`. See: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-values . Also, the errors for the wrappers are because the Component still needs a type for Props. Something like `class Wrapper1 extends Component<*>` or `class Wrapper2 extends Component<{}>` works.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working example](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgF84AzKQuAcilQwYG4AoDtEgZ3gDyAIwBWARjgBeXCgBcjFA2xD5DIQwqcexfnGEiATFNxpVaJXAAmqyxs4cYATzBI4AFWdJeAMWgBBYwASAFEAD3QYAB4nFwhqPVExAD5OGNcPFx9oACEgsIjozziEwxSuNLgA6T8oKBRHSJwAHw44ODk4YgBXECEkKExWuBV3TyyoP0GmiiTyzzhc6tr6xpa2ju7e-sG2kYyvXyhsqZm5lzgABTowXmMcMGv5AKaFzQd5gGUYFBhXaXvHpU4C9sm8OEhQpBYHA0AAbFC8W5uLzwCG-YiWW4EIikciRK4QG7YL4-JBJXBDOD8Ul3B6E+QwAAWwF4ADo6Td2dcKJTmBj+gAKACUuGYMC6UGInS6sNhPI48rhCNuAHU6mAXFAJGiyJi4NjILiogAqck4NoW3m6wUinCUtraXQcuBPYwAbRwHTEynk+jEFAAuva4GKJVLIsinddJADCRQAPTkylUC2W+XceGIuBqlAa-pGHUYrGEQ1kE1m1NwK38qDCimVx3wZ3yRZwD1en0lAyB4OhyVwCMouAcmMchNJi0pysKoA) but it might not do everything you want. The main problem seems to be that Flow can't determine the type of the elements in the `prop` array, but explicitly typing the value works, e.g.

```js
class Wrapper1 extends Component<*> {     
   render() {
     const prop : A = [{a: 1, b: Obj1}];
     return <Test prop={prop}/> 
   }       
}
```